# ModuleNotFoundError when import package from src folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

What is wrong with this python structure?
I have read multiple docs and forums on this issue i just can't seem to get it solved.

```bash
.
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── lib
    │   ├── hello.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── libtwo
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── world.py
    └── main.py
```

world.py

```py
def helloworld():
    print("Hello World!")
```

hello.py

```py
from libtwo.world import helloworld

helloworld()
```

main.py

```py
from libtwo.world import helloworld

helloworld()
```

(it runs fine from main.py)

```
  File "src/lib/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from libtwo.world import helloworld
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtwo'
```

the following gives

```
  File "lib/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..libtwo.world import helloworld
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

```py
from ..libtwo.world import helloworld

helloworld()
```

using vscode
i tried to set up workspaces and configs, all the lot.
`"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true`

(yes i am using a virtual env)

virtualenv sys path entries.

according to some sources if i don't see my directory in the virtualenv that means something is wrong

```
(my_venv) ➜  src python main.py 
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/user/Documents/py/myui/subject_a/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
>>>
```

running sys.path from main.py

```
(my_venv) ➜  src python main.py 
['/home/user/Documents/py/myui/subject_a/src', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/user/Documents/py/myui/subject_a/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

I really can't pin point what is wrong with my structure, i have been doing this for years and today nothing seems to work.

Comment: try `src.libtwo.world import helloworld`

Comment: @Sergio2405 same issue, i would have actually thought that would work because its the project root, but still the same issue

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug, I tried on my laptop with your exact structure and many config and running environment, it works for me.

Comment: @DorianTurba my issue was caused by a ppython path issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `hello.py` file, you import the module using `libtwo.world`. This means Python should look for modules from `src` directory.

When you run `main.py`, it works fine because Python looks for modules in the working directory which is `src`.

You can set `PYTHONPATH` to explicitly specify the search path for module files. Refer to https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH.

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)/src
python src/lib/hello.py
```

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for. i had a feeling it is not to do with my code structure but rather a path issue, thanks for this. i tried setting this in vscode itself with no luck but this will have to do

Answer (score 1):

sometimes vscode does not detect the package folder so you can add this to your settings.json

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
}
```